# my app crashes on running this code of adding numbers

Tags: android

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     final EditText ed1,ed2;
     Button bt;
     final TextView tx;

     tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
     bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
     ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
     ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     int a = Integer.parseInt(ed1.toString());
     int b = Integer.parseInt(ed2.toString());
     final int c = a + b;

     bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

             tx.setText(String.valueOf(c));
         }

      });


   }
}
```

Comment: what does logcat say?

Comment: Please include any errors you are getting in your debugger, otherwise it is impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

In the future, post your stack trace.  It tells you what went wrong.  In this case its obvious- you want

```
edittext.getText().toString();
```

not

```
edittext.toString();
```